# How do I grep for "->"?

Tags: shell, grep

I wanted to find out the list of java files, where I have used lambda expressions. Towards this, I wanted to grep for the expression "->". Some of the queries similar to mine got the response that grep should be used with the -F option. When I did this like:

```
grep -F "->" *.java
```

I got the error message:

```
grep: invalid option -- >
```

I am using MacOS Darwin.

Comment: Simple, I'd drop the `-F` and just use `grep '[-][>]'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put double hyphen before your keyword:

```
grep -- '->' *.java
```

Answer (score 3):

[POSIX specifies](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html#tag_20_55_04) the `-e` option. It can be used to specify *multiple* patterns, but it’s also useful for a single pattern that begins with a hyphen:

```
grep -e '->' *.java
```

Answer (score 2):

When you have 'unsafe' patterns, better the follow the pattern. It will reduce the change of parsing error - it clearly separate options from the pattern

```
grep [options] -- "REGEXP" files
```

In this case

```
grep -F -- "->" *.java
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\` to escape the `-` character, which is interpreted as an indicator for a command line argument if you don't escape it: `grep "\->" *.java`

Comment: **grep -F "\->" *.java** does not produce any output or error message. But, **grep  "\->" *.java** gives the expected result.

Comment: @SeshadriR sorry, I didn't even look into the `-F` option. I just assumed that wasn't part of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you always can do is to encapsulate the *weird* symbols in regular expression brackets (`[]`).

```
$ grep '[-][>]' file
```

This is what I would do in this case of the OP. There is a problem, the OP is now sure what the problem is, is it the hyphen (`-`) or the greater-than sign (`>`), **encapsulate**!

The problem here is, however, the hyphen. Hyphens generally signify a command/utility option. The utility `grep` sees that one of its arguments starts with a hyphen, says *"Hey, here comes an option, lets process it"*. It checks the option, sees `>`, and says *"Sorry, no can do!"*

For reasons, like the above, the Posix standard introduced the double-hypen with the following requirement:

> The requirement for recognizing `--` is because conforming applications need a way to shield their operands from any arbitrary options that the implementation may provide as an extension. For example, if the standard utility `foo` is listed as taking no options, and the application needed to give it a pathname with a leading <hyphen-minus>, it could safely do it as:
>
> ```
> foo -- -myfile
> ```
>
> and avoid any problems with `-m` used as an extension.
>
> **<sub>source: [POSIX.1-2017 Utility Description Defaults](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_04)</sub>**

Posix.1-2017 also makes this a guideline for when you write your own utilities:

> **Guideline 10:** The first `--` argument that is not an option-argument should be accepted as a delimiter indicating the end of options. Any following arguments should be treated as operands, even if they begin with the `-` character.
>
> **<sub>source: [POSIX.1-2017 Utility Syntax Guidelines](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02)</sub>**

An implementation of this guideline can be seen in [BashFAQ 035](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035).

Hence, the true solution to the problem would have been:

```
$ grep -- '->' file
```